# Pass php variable to window.open in ui-dialog

Tags: php, jquery

I am using a ui-dialog and want to pass a php variable to a url if the Delete button is clicked. I have looked at a large number of other answers to similar questions but nothing seems to quite fit what I am trying to do. 
The code below works correctly for the link shown, but doesn't work when I try to pass the php variable to the url.
This code works fine

```
$( function() {
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete": function() {
                window.open('https://example.com/page.php?id=');
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried using this but it doesn't work

```
window.open('https://example.com/page.php?id=<?php echo $id?>')
```

Comment: You can view source in web browser to see html generate to see what's wrong

Comment: is this code in a php file, or a js file?

Comment: The code is in a php file

Answer (score 0):

Try add ";" at the end.

```
<?php echo $id;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign pageid in input `hidden` fields like below.

After you need to get this fields value using val() function.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php $id; ?>" id="pageId" />

$( function() {
    var PageId = $('#pageId').val();
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete": function() {
                window.open('https://example.com/page.php?id='+PageId);
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: After  more investigation I found that the code I was using did work and the problem was in another section of code. Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your above code is in .php file, try below code:

```
<script>
$( function() {
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete": function() {
                window.open("https://example.com/page.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>");
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```